# AZcopy help for sync two destination using database mapping

Tags: azure-blob-storage, robocopy, azcopy

I need your help as new to AZ copy.
I have on -primise file share server and blob storage where client storing same files. Now I need to sync azure blob storage with on-prem by using AZCopy tool.
On-prem structure workflow – on-prem server have Attachment folder for each environment with 0-99 sub folders. Now whenever system generate loan like 100000367, all the documents associated to loan goes to last 2-digit folder (for “100000367”, all documents file go in 67 folder which loanid folder and then store all files in it.)
[image]

Azure storage workflow - have Attachment container for each environment with 0-99 sub virtual folders. Now whenever system generate loan like 100000367, all the documents associated to loan goes to last 2-digit folder (for “100000367”, all documents’ files go in 67 virtual folder which loanid virtual folder and then store all files in it.).
[image]

System storing this folder structure mapping of each file in client database table like loanid – parent folderid-child folder and files

[image]

Is there a way to script AZCopy tool to perform file to file mapping and sync both environment for each client with the help of mapping stored in database?
Any suggestion on tool or script for reference would great help…

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual directories with the blob service. In other words, there’s no need to create the virtual directories explicitly, you just name your blobs accordingly.

For example, if you name your blob /container/dir1/dir2/file.txt, you have virtual directories called dir1 which has a sub virtual directory dir2.

So if I not use file to file mapping, does AZCopy sync will both storage no matter how much nested level file storage I have?

Yes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-synchronize?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json